# Possible ways to incorporate topography in a correlated random walk in R?

Tags: r, terrain, random-walk, topography

I was wondering which possibilities there are for incorporating topography in a correlated random walk in R. I have a digital elevation model (DEM) of the study area. I would like for my random walk to avoid areas with a steep slope.

```
walk <- function(x0, y0, head0, n, parameterMu, parameterRho, parameterMean, parameterSd)
{
  # Get nr of individuals, call it k
  k = length(x0)

  # Create list to hold data
  all.paths <- list()
  
  for (j in 1:k)
  {
    # Create structure to hold data
    steps <- data.frame(matrix(0,n,6))
    colnames(steps) <- c("id","x", "y", "steplength", "heading", "turningangle")
    
    # Insert the id, starting location and heading
    steps[,"id"] = j
    steps[1,"x"] = x0[j]
    steps[1,"y"] = y0[j]
    steps[1,"heading"] = head0[j]
    
    # Simulate steps
    for(i in 2:n)
    {
      # Draw step length and turning angle, compute heading
      steplength = rnorm(n = 1, mean = parameterMean, sd = parameterSd)
      turningangle = as.numeric(rwrappedcauchy(n = 1, mu = parameterMu, rho = parameterRho))
      newbearing = as.numeric(circular(steps[i-1,"heading"]) + circular(turningangle)) %% (2*pi)
      
      # Get new location
      next.xy <- movement(x0=steps[i-1,"x"], y0=steps[i-1,"y"], step=steplength, heading=newbearing)
      
      # Store output (xy on row i, steplength/heading on row i-1)
      steps[i,"x"] <- next.xy[1,"x"]
      steps[i,"y"] <- next.xy[1,"y"]
      steps[i,"steplength"] <- next.xy[1,"step"]
      steps[i,"heading"] <- newbearing
      steps[i,"turningangle"] <- turningangle
        
    # Store trajectory in list
    all.paths[[j]] <- steps
  }
  
  # Return output
  return(all.paths)
}
```

The movement function:

```
movement <- function(x0, y0, step, heading)
{
  x_new <- x0 + sin(heading)*step
  y_new <- y0 + cos(heading)*step
  move.temp <- data.frame(x = x_new,
                          y = y_new,
                          step = step,
                          head = heading)
  return(move.temp)
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is awfully broad. You could do this by **rejection sampling**, i.e. pick a new proposed location/step; take the ratio of steepness at your current and proposed spot: if the new spot is less steep than your current spot, go there. If it is steeper, go pick a random uniform and go if `exp(-ratio/tau)<U` where `tau` is an index of habitat preference (this is basically Metropolis-Hasting sampling)

Comment: You may check the [`SiMRiv` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SiMRiv/vignettes/SiMRiv.pdf). "**5 Simulating in heterogeneous environments** [...] resistance raster [...] defines, for all pixels in space, the propensity of the individuals to move within/into each pixel [...]. Any object of
class `RasterLayer` (from the `raster` package) with values in the range [0, 1] can be used, where 0 means a pixel with no resistance and 1 a pixel with ’infinite’ resistance (i.e. where the individual cannot move)." Disclaimer: I haven't used it myself, but a student once mentioned it.